# How to set datepicker using webdriverIO?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, webdriver-io

I have a task where I need to automate the booking.com page, and one of the tasks is to select check-in and check-out dates. How I can do this? I automated , that I can open calendar,[image] but I don't know how to select dates.

Here is my code 
**Cucumber step**

```
    And user selects dates from "2020-06-16" to "2020-06-26"
```

**BookingStep**

```
When('user selects dates from {string} to {string}',()=>{
BookingPage.checkInOut.click();
browser.debug();  });
```

**Booking page**

```
class BookingPage{
get whereAreYouGoingTextBox(){return $('#ss')};
get checkInOut(){return $('div.xp__dates-inner')};  }export default new BookingPage();
```

Comment: You are able to inspect the dates?

Comment: Yes sure im able to inspect dates

Comment: Try clicking on a date and generate dynamic xpath. So,that you can pass the date as a argument and click on any date

Comment: I can do this without xpath? using only css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: My answer is a solution for the ability to set a value in the date field, and only interact with the cancel link on the date picker object.

I battled this for a while and came up with a solution that works for me, I hope it works for you also.

First when I inspect the datepicker object, it generates a random XPATH/CSS Selector. As a result if you inspect & copy the selector and try to use it in your next test, it will fail since the xpath/selector is randomly generated. I got around this issue by identifying a unique css ID that lived above the datepicker element, and used that as my starting point. Then I looked at the html path from that point to the datepicker input tag, and I appended that path. This solved the first problem of not being able to set a value in the date picker text field. Here is an example using xpath:

//*[@id="filtersSideBar"] - This is the unique ID found above the datepicker

/div[2]/div/input - This is the path to the date picker from the unique ID

```
$('//*[@id="filtersSideBar"]/div[2]/div/input').waitForClickable(3000);
$('//*[@id="filtersSideBar"]/div[2]/div/input').setValue('2020-01-01');
```

Now that you have a date inside the date picker field, you have to close the datepicker object. I had to use Javascript to accomplish this. First open the datepicker object, then inspect the 'Cancel' link element. Copy the CSS Selector ID. Lets say it ends up being #cancelLink

Now you run this code:

```
browser.execute(() => document.querySelector('#cancelLink').click());
```

Which will then close the datepicker object so that you can proceed with your testing.

Here is my actual code:

```
class DataSearchSortAndDateRangePage {
                                   
    get startDate() { return $('//
[@id="filtersSideBar"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/input'); }

    setStartDate(date) {
        this.startDate.waitForClickable( { timeout: browser.config.timeOutValue } );
        this.startDate.setValue(date);
        browser.execute(() => document.querySelector('body > div.md-datepicker-dialog.md-theme-default > div.md-datepicker-body > div.md-dialog-actions.md-datepicker-body-footer > button > div > div').click());        
    }
}

export default new DataSearchSortAndDateRangePage();
```

I hope this helps out =)